# R packages with Rcpp and nloptr

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, nlopt, rcppparallel

I have been building an r-package that runs RcppParallel and calls nloptr from the cpp in parallel.  Currently, the package will not build as it can't find the 'nloptrAPI.h' file.

The build log outputs: 
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Namespaces in Imports field not imported from:
  ‘RcppArmadillo’ ‘nloptr’

My question is if there is a simple fix for this.  Or if I would have to rewrite the function to call 'nlopt' from the cpp version and add a 'makevars' file to the package.

The src only contains my written functions and the generated RcppExports.

Comment: I think you need to show us your package structure.

Comment: Do you have something like `LinkingTo: nloptr (>1.1.0)` in your `DESCRIPTION`?

Comment: Within the description I; Imports:  nloptr ( >= 1.1.9) and LinkingTo: nloptr

Comment: There is quite a bit of discussion in an issue ticket of the nloptr repo; I also believe you need the github version supports the header file interface whereas the CRAN version may not.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk.  The GitHub version solved this problem quickly and easily.  As I am thinking about publishing my work, I thought I should ask about using the GitHub 'nloptr' over the 'nlopt cpp'.